# Firefox home page change without Edit Preference option

Tags: firefox

My version of Firefox does not give me a Preferences option under the Edit tab. It just is not there.
How can I change my Internet Home Page without this option?

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 3):

In the browser, navigate to the `about:config` page. Then, search for `browser.startup.homepage` and change that variable to your desired homepage.

There is no need to restart your browser for this to take effect. The change should take place immediately.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I agree with maggotbrain answer.  Also, depending on your version of FF, you could have a Firefox button, that leads you to preferences.  See image below.

[image]

Also you can go under Help-->Restart with Add-ons Disabled, and see if that helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to change the homepage (that should work) is:

1. Navigate to the page you want to set as homepage
2. Drag the tab of the page from the top and drop it on the Homepage button (the one that looks like a house, at least in the default theme, unless it's hidden)
3. Confirm the new homepage in the message box that *should* appear